# How to type in the xPath expression (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I got following problem:

I used the Google Chrome function for getting the xPath expression for a button but i don't know how to use this expression in my java code.

I got following expression from Google Chrome: //*[@id="watch8-sentiment-actions"]/span/span[3]/button

I want to use this xPath expression in the following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

 driver.get(url);

 driver.findElement(By.xpath(" "));
```

Comment: This is badly designed, brittle xpath locator. If you can share HTML code of the web page, someone may help you create a proper one.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='watch8-sentiment-actions']/span/span[3]/button"));
```

Mind the single quotation marks inside the xpath-expression!

no you could also click the button for example:

```
button.click();
```

After a bit of research, I now know, that this button is the downvote-button of youtube, so better only try this code with your own videos.

Comment: i typed this in but i got following error code:

Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.css.sac.CSSException: Invalid selector: *:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor

Comment: sorry had some typos in the code, of course the button is a "WebElement" and we need single quotation marks inside the xpath-expression, should work now

Answer (score 0):

It is much better like that:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='watch8-sentiment-actions']/span/span[3]/button")).click();
```

Comment: Dominik Q , Was it helpful for you?